# Google API to manage location reviews for a 3rd party

Tags: google-api, review, google-location-services, google-console-developer

I'm working with a client who would like to integrate management of google reviews into an existing app (used by many franchise locations).

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get access to review data from a 3rd party.

The "Google My Business API" requires filling out a form, and seems to be for your own business only. And obviously I don't want to have to ask every franchise to create a new API in the google API console so I can get access.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/

Each franchise has a google "my business" account they use to see reviews and manage their location, but that's it. No api access, etc.

Is there some way to get at these APIs with OAuth? How do reputation apps get access to this information?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found solution?

Comment: @pelcomppl Yes. Once you are approved you can get third-party access to manage reviews. Use OAuth to get a token and request the permission, upon callback to your app you can send the token to your server which does a seperate request to get a server access token. You can also use this access token to get a refresh token.

I was unable to get any of this to work using their libraries - only had success from piecing together the correct workflow as determined from various forum and support threads.

Comment: @Aelast Could you please give some more details, how did you get all works together, I still have the same problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Aelast "Once you are approved you can get third-party access to manage reviews", how/where do you start the process to become approved?